# Minecraft Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My full error:

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main`

I just installed Minecraft 1.8.9 on OSX El Capitan and tried to play offline since my wifi connection has some issues, and I ran into the error above.

Here is the log link: https://gist.github.com/leongaban/08bc199c463d70b25dcc

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The java HotSpot part is always there, it's not a problem. Did it work when playing online? If you haven't tried, please do. Also, with the finder, go to `~/Libary/Application Support/minecraft/versions` and check if there is a folder called `1.8.9` with two files in it (one `.jar` and one `.json`).

Comment: I can play both offline and online now, after a successful wifi connection.... I think it re-downloaded some stuff and it fixed it.

Comment: you should make that an answer.

Comment: Just curious, because of the first line in the log saying it could not connect to libraries.minecraft.net, could you ping that hostname and see if it times out or works? `ping libraries.minecraft.net` Edit: just to clarify, if it needs to download files from their server and it can't, that can cause problems, but I don't know if that would cause the error in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I was able to connect to Wifi again, the software updated and I was able to play online and offline with no problems.

Bug was trying to play Minecraft on Wifi in the Philippines.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have had this problem before. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

That might work, although I am not sure.

Also, make sure you have played Minecraft once when you are online.

Comment: More info on this: This updates the `ca-certificates` on Debian-based linux repos (`Debian`, `Ubuntu`, etc...), which are used to access the internet in certain scenarios.