# Launcher is unable to find net.minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I just bought Minecraft and downloaded it. When I opened the launcher after logging in, it started downloading, but then just before it finished the download it disappeared and this error popped up:

[image: please help!]

I tried deleting the launcher, the .minecraft folder, and then re-downloading it but it didn't work either.

Comment: Did you install Minecraft with the .msi installer?

Comment: no with the .exe

Comment: does the .msi need admin rights?

Comment: I'd recommend installing the newest version of Java then.  Or try the .msi, as it comes with Java.  msi Installers will most likely need admin privileges.

Comment: but i dont have admin privileges :(

Comment: I don't know how to fix that problem, but I do know that that error means that Minecraft cannot find the main Java class, needed to run Minecraft

Comment: @RavenM the new `.exe` also includes the runtime. The `.msi` simply allows you to select a directory to install the `.exe` in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft Error: Could not find or load main class](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248668/minecraft-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Answer (score 2):

```
Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
```

This means that Minecraft was not correctly installed.

Essentially, the launcher could not find one the files needed for Minecraft. Check if your profile is set to a valid Minecraft version, or that the Minecraft version jar is a valid one. You can also try and select a different Minecraft version and see if that works. If it does, it probably means that the jar file you want to use is corrupted. In that case, try and delete the version jar file and relaunch the game.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to install Java. There may be a tricky way to do it without admin, but you will still need to figure out how to set environment variables correctly.  [Portable Java](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) is a popular solution.

Comment: The launcher is clearly running, meaning that java, or at least the Minecraft java runtime, is installed, since the launcher is java-based as well.